# How to create authentication rest api in odoo 14?

Tags: odoo-14

I want to create rest API in odoo14 for authentication using postman.
like register user and login user api

Answer (score 0):

Odoo comes equipped with API keys and its own authentication module, with each user having an API key. Take a look at their documentation [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/misc/api/odoo.html).